# Creating first docker container: Can't find host system file on build

Tags: docker

I'm trying to bundle my Jekyll blog as a docker container.

I found this Dockerfile which seems to suit my use case but wanted to be more hands on so I copied it directly into my repo:

```
FROM ruby:latest
MAINTAINER Peter Etelej <peter@etelej.com>

RUN apt-get -qq update && \
  apt-get -qq install nodejs -y && \
  gem install -q bundler

RUN mkdir -p /etc/jekyll && \
  printf 'source "https://rubygems.org"\ngem "github-pages"\ngem "execjs"\ngem "rouge"' > /etc/jekyll/Gemfile && \
  printf "\nBuilding required Ruby gems. Please wait..." && \
  bundle install --gemfile /etc/jekyll/Gemfile --clean --quiet

RUN apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENV BUNDLE_GEMFILE /etc/jekyll/Gemfile

EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

CMD ["jekyll", "serve","--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

When I run it I get an error

`jekyll 3.4.3 | Error:  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`

The host system has this file but my assumption was that the container didn't have access to it so I tried to add it into the Dockerfile

`ADD /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`

I then docker build and get the error

`lstat etc/modules-load.d/: no such file or directory`

I don't understand why the container is looking for this file in the first place but I'm even more confused by the fact that I can't add a file which is clearly there.

Comment: Here are some tips.   #1 - if you have a static file, just add it.   All those printf's add zero value and non-zero complexity.   #2 - slap everything on CMD until you get it figured out (eliminate entrypoint just for ease of use/debugging, you can override it on the cmdline but why bother until you get it buttoned down).   #3 - then run "docker run -it --rm imagename /bin/sh"    You are then inside the container and can run, test, debug your command and your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker builds run on the docker host, not necessarily the client where you run the command, and so all the files needed to run the build are sent in the build context to the host. That context is most often the current directory, or `.`, that you pass at the end of the `docker build -t $image_name .` command.

Everything that you try to include in the image with a `COPY` or `ADD` is done in reference to that build context, not the filesystem on your client or host machine. So if you need a modules.conf, you'll need to first copy that into your directory with the Dockerfile, and then `COPY` the file from there.

As for why jekyll is looking for the file, I'm not familiar with jekyll, but it doesn't look promising for something running inside of a container. The modules are kernel specific and containers are designed to be moved to different hosts with potentially different kernels.

Comment: You didn't answer my question directly but I think you made me see that I was asking the wrong question. Thanks for the info!